# Sharing map markup using ArcGIS Portal?

Tags: arcgis-portal, widget, map-notes

When deploying ArcGIS Portal, we have the ability to add a draw widget to our map app using Web AppBuilder.  However, when users draw on the map, and they try to share this markup with other users, the drawings do not show up.

Is there a way for our users to markup the map using the draw widget, or similar functionality, and be able to share that with other users?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Think of markup as simply another hosted feature layer.  You can create a 'Map Notes' layer from a default template within My Content.  Add the editing tool to AppBuilder.  You can also make use of editor ownership to ensure markup is not editable by other users.

Alternatively, make use of the [draw widget](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/create-apps/widget-draw.htm) and [save session widget](https://community.esri.com/docs/DOC-7661).

Comment: I will be looking into the Save Session Widget.  Is it pretty stable and reliable?

The problem I have with using another hosted feature layer is that it will require that users be Level 2 named users if they want or need this functionality.

Comment: Have seen several orgs with the Save Session widget in production environment and no issues.